# Pillow is not installed error even after installation

Tags: python, django

as per tutorial I am following they ask me install pillow for file upload functionality.

so for that I used command:

> `pip install pillow`

and

> `pytho-m pip install Pillow`

and both return result:

```
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (3.1.2)
```

But when run my local server it shows error in terminal:

```
ERRORS:
book.Book.picture: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".
```

I do not understand is pillow install or not.

Comment: When I sometimes run into similar problems, it's because I were installing python2 versions of the library while trying to run my program using python3. So first and foremost, I'd make sure that's not the case for your situation.

Comment: you can have two python installed and you install module in one Python but you run code with other Python. OR you run server in `venv` but you installed module before avtivate `venv` so it is not installled in `venv`

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments? You really should, it solves a lot of these issues.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: @DataGreed using virtual env works for me